# What is the speed of gluons inside a proton or neutron?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

I have got the following answer to the above question from ChatGPT 4. Is this answer correct?

Any more new information that can added as an answer?

*"The propagation speed of gluons inside a proton is a topic of ongoing research and there is no consensus on a fixed value. Gluons are massless gauge bosons that carry the strong nuclear force, and their interactions with the proton are described by Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD). The QCD Lagrangian describes the gluon field as a set of point-like particles, which are free to propagate through the proton, but the exact speed at which they do so is not a well-defined quantity. Different methods to calculate the gluon propagator in QCD lead to slightly different results, and there is currently no experimental evidence that can pin down the gluon speed."-ChatGPT v4.*

Comment: ChatGPT is a *language* model, not a physics model. It produces sentences that are statistically similar to its training data, but it has no mechanism to evaluate their truth, or even their underlying logic. ChatGPT can be an interesting tool to help formulate questions, but you need to check its results against credible sources.

Comment: I think you'd enjoy Frank Wilczek's [Core](https://www.frankwilczek.com/core.html) articles. He explains how gluons are like photons in a superconductor. He develops that model further in his book, [The Lightness of Being](https://www.lightnessofbeingbook.com/).

Comment: How would you even define the "speed" of "a gluon" inside a proton or neutron. Depending on what you mean, the question is completely nonsensical...or completely answerable by the momentum fraction in [parton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parton_(particle_physics)) distribution functions...

Answer (score 1):

ChatGPT doesn't really know what it is talking about.
Most of the answer is only loosely related to the
topic of your question without actually answering it.

The single important (and actually correct) part of its answer is this:

> which are free to propagate through the proton, but the
> exact speed at which they do so is not a well-defined quantity.

Actually the gluons inside a nucleon are [virtual particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle).
That means, they are short-lived particles, emitted by a [quark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark),
existing for a short time ($\approx 10^{-23}$ s), and then
absorbed by a quark.
Therefore their kinematic and dynamic properties (like position,
speed, momentum, energy) are not well-defined,
and hence there is no answer to your question.